# Finding documents matching an array inside object inside an array matching specific in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to filter a MongoDB collection with a structure similar to:

```
{
   Name: "My Item",
   Attributes: [{
        AttributeId: 1,
        Values: [{
               Name: "Book",
               P: 10
        },
        {
               Name: "Series",
               P: 100
        }] 
      },
      {   
        AttributeId: 2,
        Values: [{
              Name: "Pen",
              P: 10
        },
        {
              Name: "Dozen",
              P: 100
        }]
  }]
}
```

What I want is to get all documents with AttributeId: 1 and has a value inside it named "Book".

I have tried this filter but it didn't return any results:

```
{"ProductAttributeMappings.ProductAttributeId": 32,"ProductAttributeMappings.$.ProductAttributeValues.Name":"Book"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to do this:

This query checks inside `Attributes` array to match both conditions (Attribute==32 and Values.Name==Book)

```
db.ProductAttributeMappings.find({
  Attributes: {
    $elemMatch: {
      AttributeId: 32,
      Values: {
        $elemMatch: {
          Name: "Book"
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZMvOBSqvfmz)

But, this query checks inside entire top-level document if any array meets query condition:

```
db.ProductAttributeMappings.find({
  "Attributes.AttributeId": 32,
  "Attributes.Values.Name": "Book"
})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3Otf6e0mhLB)

Answer (score 1):

You need [elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) operator:

```
{Attributes: {$elemMatch: {AttributeId: 1, "Values.Name": "Book"}}}
```